# Assignment of a variable inside an array causes change of value

Tags: arrays, matlab, char

I'm trying to assign a variable to an array by `SNR_full(1,1) = SNR`. The `SNR_full` is initialized by `SNR_full = zeros(9,8);`

However, when I assign `SNR_full(1,1)=SNR`, `SNR` is an integer, with a value of 2, but when I checked `SNR_full(1,1)=SNR` it shows 50 instead of 2. I could manually assign `SNR_full(1,1)=2`, and it turns out to be 2.

Why would this happen?

```
%-----------------------------------------
input_string_1 = 'SynData2_12F20SNR2.asc';
input_string_2 = 'GroundTruth2_12F20.asc';

[input_normalized, input_ground, threshold_vector, threshold_vector_spike, ...
 seizures, SNR, Frequency_input, Frequency_ground, TP_get, FP_get] = ...
 SARADC_with_Threshold_func_ver(input_string_1, input_string_2);

input_normalized_full(1,1,1:length(input_normalized)) = input_normalized;
input_ground_full(1,1,1:length(input_ground)) = input_ground;
threshold_vector_full(1,1,1:length(threshold_vector)) = threshold_vector;
threshold_vector_spike_full(1,1,1:length(threshold_vector_spike)) = threshold_vector_spike;
seizures_full(1,1,1:length(seizures)) = seizures;
SNR_full(1,1) = SNR;
Frequency_input_full(1,1) = Frequency_input;
Frequency_ground_full(1,1) = Frequency_ground;
TP_full(1,1) = TP_get;
FP_full(1,1) = FP_get;
%-----------------------------------------
```

**Edit**:

Breakpoint set at `SNR_full(1,1) = SNR`, when `SNR` is 2.

**More info from comments**: `SNR` is actually a CHAR of 2, because I got SNR from `input_1_string` (`'SynData2_12F20SNR2.asc'`) by analyzing the letters.

Before the breakpoint, `SNR_full` has all zeros.

This is the initialization of all the variables

```
%-----------------------------------------
%Data for everything
input_normalized_full = zeros(9,8,25000);
input_ground_full = zeros(9,8,2);
threshold_vector_spike_full = zeros(9,8,250000);
seizures_full = zeros(9,8,250000);
SNR_full = zeros(9,8);
Frequency_input_full = zeros(9,8);
Frequency_ground_full = zeros(9,8);
TP_full = zeros(9,8);
FP_full = zeros(9,8);
%-----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `whos SNR` right before the `SNR_full(1,1) = SNR;` line? Set a breakpoint if necessary. Thanks.

Comment: What make this function:`SARADC_with_Threshold_func_ver(input_string_1, input_string_2);` How it initializes `SNR` value? You need to look for the problem in this function.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but how about the `whos SNR` or `class(SNR)` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is the side effect of automatic conversion from `char` to a numeric type, if `SNR` turns out to be a `char`. The characters `'0123456789'` have the ASCII character codes 48 through 57. When you assign one of these single characters to an element of a numerical array, the character is converted into its numeric representation.  That is,

```
>> char(48:57)
ans =    
0123456789
>> double('0123456789')
ans =    
    48    49    50    51    52    53    54    55    56    57
```

When you make an assignment of one of these characters to a numeric array, this is what happens:

```
>> x=1:2
x =
     1     2
>> x(2) = '2'    
x =
     1    50
```

If this was the problem, a fix would be to use `str2num` or `str2double` (e.g. `SNR_full(1,1) = str2num(SNR);`).

Comment: This is my answer based on the conjecture that `SNR` is a `char` instead of a numeric type.  It seemed like a decent guess, but it may turn out to be wrong. Just comment if this isn't it and I'll delete the answer. No need to downvote if my idea turned out to be silly. :)

Comment: I just started learning Matlab a day ago. And did not think about this issue. SNR is actually a CHAR of 8. Because I got SNR from input_1_string by analyzing the letters. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user1157751 That explains it I think.  But you mean `char` of `'2'`? That would give numeric 50. I see you edited your question from 8->2.

Comment: Yeah, it is numeric 2. Sometimes it is numeric 8 as well. Sorry about the confusion.